# SIGSEGV Error in short C code

Tags: c, function, pointers, segmentation-fault

So, as someone who is fairly new to C, I came across my first SIGSEGV Error. 
It appeared in a short C  program that is meant to be a "guess the number" game. It consists of a self-defined function that compares two numbers and a do-while loop with an input inside it.
The start and the do-while loop:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int checkNum(int num1, int num2); //See below for explanation

int main(void) {
    int input=0, rand=3; //"Random" number has fixed value for testing

    do {
        printf("Enter number from 0-10: "); //There is not actual range yet
        scanf("%d",input); //Get input
    } while(checkNum(input, rand)); //Checks if difference != 0
}
```

The function for comparing:

```
//Function for comparing input with "random" number
int checkNum(int num1,int num2) { //The two numbers that get compared; First one: input, Second one: "random" rumber
    if(num1==num2) {
        printf("Correct. The random number was %d",num2);
    } else if(num1<num2) {
        printf("Wrong. The random number is bigger.");
    } else if(num1>num2) {
        printf("Wrong. The random number is smaller.");
    }
    return num2-num1; //Return the difference, leads to 0 if equal
}
```

I suspect the error to be in the function, caused by a missing use of a pointer, but as far as I understand pointers, they don't seem necessary here: I don't change a single variable in the function, and the return only subtracts two values (which are given I assume).

I hope my error isn't too stupid, and I'd like to thank everyone who can help or tries to.
(I can post my processor values, altough I am not sure if that will help; If any more information is needed for debugging, please tell me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
    scanf("%d",input); //Get input
```

should be:

```
    scanf("%d",&input); //Get input
              ^^^
```

Pro tip: always compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) and the compiler will happily point out simple mistakes such as this, saving you a lot of time and grief.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help; The problem was resolved, but what confused me a little is, that the "debug" function in my c editor ("Dev-cpp", a c++ and c compiler) seemed to also cause a sigsegv sometimes; however it stopped appearing and now works properly.